# How to show that two variables of inductive type are inequal if their fields are not equal?

Tags: logic, coq

Suppose I have an inductive type:

```
Inductive addr : Type :=  mk_addr : Z -> Z -> addr.
```

Is it possible to prove the following goal?

```
Goal
  forall (x y z : Z),
  y <> z -> mk_addr x y <> mk_addr x z.
```

Answer (score 3):

`congruence` can take care of it:

```
Goal
  forall (x y z : Z),
  y <> z -> mk_addr x y <> mk_addr x z. 

congruence.
Qed.
```

Alternatively, you can prove the contrapositive of that statement:

```
Goal
 forall (x y z : Z),
 y <> z -> mk_addr x y <> mk_addr x z.
intros x y z H1 H2.
apply H1.
injection H2.
trivial.
Qed.
```